# Check if unsaved workbook is closed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that when opened, creates another blank workbook that may have some data copied across to it.  I want to test when closing the workbook whether the created workbook is still open.

I tested this on a blank workbook. For the 'ThisWorkbook' code I have

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Refreshwkbk Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "other wkbk closed"
    Else
        MsgBox "other wkbk open"
        Refreshwkbk.Activate
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call myRefresh
End Sub
```

And in a module I have

```
Public Refreshwkbk As Workbook

Sub myRefresh()
    Set Refreshwkbk = Workbooks.Add
End Sub
```

The code will break at `Refreshwkbk.Activate` with an automation error.
The error is `Run-time error '-2147221080 (800401a8)'`

How would I test that the newly created workbook is still open?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. It worked just as expected: If I open the workbook it opens another new workbook. If I close it then it says "other wkbk open", activates it, closes itself. No Error.

Comment: Thanks for trying this.  Could you try opening the test workbook, close the created workbook and then close the test workbook please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way would be trying to `.Activate` it and if that throws an error it is already closed.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    On Error GoTo WKBK_CLOSED
    Refreshwkbk.Activate 'if that fails it jumps to WKBK_CLOSED
    MsgBox "other wkbk open"

    Exit Sub
WKBK_CLOSED:
    MsgBox "other wkbk closed"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for that.  It was driving me batty.  I thought there must be a way of telling if the workbook had been closed, but perhaps that only works for saved workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better way doing this with objects, but here is an approach looping through all opened workbooks.

```
Dim wb As Workbook

'looping through currently opened workbooks
For Each wb In Workbooks
    If wb.Name = refreshwkbk.Name Then
        refreshwkbk.Activate
        MsgBox "other wkbk open"
    Else
        If refreshwkbk Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "other wkbk closed"
        End If
    End If
Next wb
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I get the same automation error when the Refreshwkbk is closed.

Comment: Lol - I read your comment about 4 times.  Was getting dizzy there.  Added a space now.

Comment: @Glib I can not reproduce your error neither, same as PeH, maybe it is something with your form controls? I remember I had a similar error from not naming my form subs correctly.

Comment: No forms involved in the workbook - I have been testing this on a totally blank workbook and when the newly created workbook is closed first, then the test workbook can't tell that it has been closed.  I will try repeating on another computer.

Comment: I think the issue with this approach is that if `refreshwkbk` is already closed, then `refreshwkbk.Name` would throw an error, because there is no `.Name` of a workbook that does not exist anymore. That's why this code cannot work.